# Installation fails for Eloquent using composer

Tags: php, eloquent, composer-php

Installing illuminate/database via composer fails and generate the following error:

> **"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."**
>   Problem 1
>       - illuminate/database v5.2.0 requires illuminate/support 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24,
>   v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37,
>   v5.2.43, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
>
> - illuminate/support v5.2.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are
>
> > enabled in those .ini files:
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
> >         - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
>
> **"Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content."**

I am want to use Eloquent to connect Slim PHP application to a database. I have used the following command to add Eloquent to the application locally:

> php composer.phar require illuminate/database "~5.1"

**I also tried:**

> php composer.phar require illuminate/database.

How to install Illuminate\Database\Eloquent | Laravel via composer ?.

Comment: "the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system" and "To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files". Have you made sure you have the mbstring extension installed and enabled?

Comment: okay, now it has worked! I installed the mbstring PHP extension 

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you what is wrong, and hints at what you should do:

> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files

You need to install (or maybe just enable) [PHP's mbstring extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). The exact procedure will depend on your operating system and also how you installed PHP in the first place.